# Read different versions of Staged files in aws S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a use case where I have different versions of files in the AWS S3 Stage area. Now I want to read a specific version of these files and load them in snowflake.

Comment: Each versioned file in S3 has its own VersionID, did you try solving it this way? I don't think Snowflake has some internal functionality to solve this issue smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> COPY INTO command.

In your case since there are different versions of the files, it is recommended that you partition the files based on some suffix or prefix.
Once this is done you can create an external Stage and point the stage to a specific S3 folder, so you are reading only a particular version of Files from S3.
Here you are saving time and cost, as you are scanning only a specific S3 folder which contains the files and not the entire S3 bucket.

More details can be found here -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-files-directly-from-an-external-location